# How to auto indent html written as a string?

Tags: javascript, html, indentation, auto-indent

I have a looong string of HTML inside a Javascript.

Is there any way I can auto indent it?

The conventional way in Sublime Text (pressing `F12`) won't work because Sublime doesn't know it's HTML.

Here's a portion of it:

```
        '<ul class="obj-ul">' +
        '<li ng-repeat="(key, val) in argVal">' +
        '<p class="arg-key">{{key}}</p>' +
        '<span class="arg-colon">:</span>' +
        '<div ng-if="utils.isPrimitive(val)" class="inline-block">'+
        '<p ng-click="editVal=!editVal" ng-show="!editVal" class="arg-val">{{argVal[key]}}</p>' +
        '<input ng-show="editVal" ng-model="argVal[key]" ng-blur="editVal=!editVal" class="arg-val" />' +
        '</div>'+
        '<div ng-if="!utils.isPrimitive(val)" class="inline-block">'+
        '<rapid-args arg-val="argVal[key]"></rapid-args>' +
        '</div>'+
        '</li>' +
        '<div ng-if="utils.showButtons.showButtonInObject(templateArgVal)">' +
        '<button ng-click="vars.show_addObjectItem=!vars.show_addObjectItem">+</button>'+
        '<div ng-if="vars.show_addObjectItem" class="add-item">'+
        '<input ng-model="newKey" type="text" class="arg-key"/>'+
        '<span class="arg-colon">:</span>' +
        '<div id="new-value">'+
        '<div ng-if="!vars.show_addObjectValue" class="value-types">'+
        '<p ng-click="objects.addItem(argVal, newKey, \'array\'); vars.show_addObjectItem=!vars.show_addObjectItem" class="value-types-type">Array</p>'+
        '<p ng-click="objects.addItem(argVal, newKey, \'object\'); vars.show_addObjectItem=!vars.show_addObjectItem" class="value-types-type">Object</p>'+
        '<p ng-click="vars.show_addObjectValue=!vars.show_addObjectValue" class="value-types-type">String</p>'+
        '<p>{{showValInput}}</p>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div ng-if="vars.show_addObjectValue">'+
        '<input ng-model="newVal" type="text" class="arg-key"/>'+
        '<button ng-click="objects.addNewKeyVal(argVal, newKey, newVal); vars.show_addObjectValue=!vars.show_addObjectValue">&#10003</button>'+
        '<button ng-click="vars.show_addObjectValue=!vars.show_addObjectValue">Cancel</button>'+
        '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>'+
        '</ul>' +
```

Comment: i would put this in a template file.

Comment: Or since it is for angular, put it in an ng-template script tag

Comment: Use *Notepad++*, clear all the quotes on the first line using `column select` (`ALT - MOUSELEFT`), strip all the single quotes and `+`es with a regex (`'\s?+`) in the *search and replace window* and then use *Sublime*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort of what Mouser suggested in a comment, you're going to have to remove the apostrophe's and plus signs from this code using a find+replace tool (notepad++ has one, I'm sure sublime will have one too) then do your formatting thing with F12 in sublime and then re-add your apostrophe's and plus signs using regex.

Here's a demonstration of how to remove your string formatting using Notepad++ (or any Regex based find and replace string manipulator):

Find What: *'(.*?)'[\s]?\+*

Replace With: *$1*

[image: http://i.imgur.com/UhrNIYd.gif]

To add them back again after you've formatted you can simply do:

Find What: *(.*)*

Replace With: *'$1' +*

Comment: can you explain the regex? What does `'(.*?)'[\s]?+` mean in English?

Comment: Sure thing. It first searches for an apostrophe, then the brackets create a group for us to spit out the other side ($1). The full stop basically means "any character" the * means "0 or more" and the ? tells it to not be greedy so its grabbing "0 or more of any character, up to the first apostrophe it finds". "[\s]" is a space character and the ? after this means that this is optional and might not be there. Then finally it grabs the + at the end. $1 spits out everything we grabbed in the parenthesis. If we had another group, we would spit that out with "$2". Does that help? :)

Comment: Problem: When I try to put the apostrophe back, it puts it around the plus signs too and adds another, for example `'<div>+'+`. This is no good. I need the plus sign to be outside of the quotations

Comment: @Imray Is your "Replace With" statement _'$1' +_ ?

Comment: I updated my comment above. It's adding a `+` sign inside the quotations.

Comment: @Imray I've just noticed something. SO decided to remove a \ in my code above. Try the whole thing now with the extra \ behind the +. The \ is needed to escape the + sign to tell it that it's a literal character and not a regex object. The code you will have been using won't have been removing your + sign. \*rolls eyes\*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72144/discussion-between-jamie-barker-and-imray).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way:

1. Remove all the quotes and `+` used to concatenate the different lines, i.e., make it a single string (you may use search-replace -> replace all) without any `+` in between to join.
2. Copy the resulting string and paste at http://www.freeformatter.com/html-formatter.html or any other online html formatter.
3. Copy the result and paste it back.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Remove all the quotes? That will take me hours!

Comment: Use search-replace with search string as `' + '` and replace string as `' '` and hit replace all or as suggested by @Mouser use Notepad++ (column select).

Comment: @Imray My answer demonstrates a very simple method to batch remove all apostrophes and plus signs from your code.